# CSS semi-circle effect

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create a unique shape using solely CSS.

Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/u6vu96u8/

However, there is too much `flat` at the base of the semi-circle. 
Is it possible, I can just get the curves to meet exactly in the middle without the flat line?

**Code:**

```css
button {
  font-size: 1em;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #1588cb;
  color: #1588cb;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 60px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px 0 50px 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -o-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.full-circle {
  border: 1px solid #1588cb;
  height: 35px;
  width: 45px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -o-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-radius: 0 0 45px 45px;
  border-top: none;
  height: 15px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -17px;
  bottom: -16px;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>News
  <span class="full-circle">+</span>
</button>
```

Comment: you have two declared height in your `.full-circle` class, only the latter will be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 height attributes on the full-circle class, was a bit confusing until I removed the first one.

```
button {
    font-size: 1em;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #1588cb;
    color: #1588cb;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 60px;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 25px 0 50px 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -o-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.full-circle {
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid #1588cb;
    width: 45px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -o-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border-radius: 0 0 60px 60px;
    border-top: none;
    height: 25px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -17px;
    bottom: -26px;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hj3g3gjL/

---

Update:

I sort of got it working... Either way, you owe me a beer!

```
.full-circle {
        display:block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #1588cb;
        width: 45px;
        -moz-border-radius: 45px / 36px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 45px / 36px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        -o-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
        border-radius: 45px / 36px;
        height: 35px;
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -17px;
        bottom: -17px;
        line-height: 40px;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/awea2s2y/

or maybe this one is slightly better? https://jsfiddle.net/p9hynbrb/

Comment: Hi Darren, thanks for this. Apologies for the `height` duplicate value. Is there any way to have this semi-circle shape be `45px wide` and `16px height`?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Check out the update, it's close.. I've had enough fiddling for one day!

Comment: So sorry for my delay. Thank you so much for your efforts. Is there any way to fix the way the semi circle border tapers off on either side, see how the border goes thin. Can we fix that?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk I had a quick play about but couldn't get a line the whole way around. You might want to consider using a background image for this?

Comment: Thank you, Darren. It's indeed a bit of a beast - and I'm getting odd issues between Chrome & Firefox now :-/

Answer (score 4):

Your full-circle class has a width of 45px, whereas it has a border radius of 30px. If you want it to be a semicircle, you need the same border radius as width. Changing the width to 30px appears to do what you want (try it)

Comment: Well, that was easy :-D Thank you so much!!

Comment: @michaelmcgurk No problem. Incidentally, you've set the "height" property on your full-circle class twice (you've set it to 35px at the top, 15px near the bottom). Only one of these will take effect, having two will just cause confusion

Answer (score 3):

You can play with height and bottom css properties for the `.full-circle` class

```css
button {
    font-size: 1em;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #1588cb;
    color: #1588cb;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 60px;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 25px 0 50px 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -o-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.full-circle {
    border: 1px solid #1588cb;
    height: 35px;
    width: 45px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -o-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border-radius: 0 0 45px 45px;
    border-top: none;
    height: 19px;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -17px;
    bottom: -20px;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>News<span class="full-circle">+</span></button>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6vu96u8/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You could decrease the width to match the border-radius.

```css
button {
    font-size: 1em;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #1588cb;
    color: #1588cb;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 60px;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 25px 0 50px 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -o-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.full-circle {
    border: 1px solid #1588cb;
    height: 15px;
    width: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -o-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border-radius: 0 0 45px 45px;
    border-top: none;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -17px;
    bottom: -16px;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>News<span class="full-circle">+</span></button>
```